# Use Template in GTEST (Googletest)

Tags: c++, templates, googletest

I know. The headline is not perfekt. Perhaps I fund a better Headline later.
I have a Problem with GTEST with template.
(Yes I know. The code make no sense. It is a sample).
I have the following template:

```
template<typename T>
   struct MY_VALUE{};

template<>
    struct MY_VALUE<uint8_t>{
        static const uint8_t val = 8;
    };

template<>
    struct MY_VALUE<uint16_t>{
        static const uint16_t val = 16;
};
```

I can test the code with (test sucess):

```
TEST(MY_VALUE_test, test) {
    uint32_t var8 = MY_VALUE<uint8_t>::val;
    ASSERT_EQ(8, var8);

    uint32_t var16 = MY_VALUE<uint16_t>::val;
    ASSERT_EQ(16, var16);
}
```

But when i try to test this, the LINKER give me an error:

```
TEST(MY_VALUE_test, test1) {
    ASSERT_EQ(8, MY_VALUE<uint8_t>::val);
    ASSERT_EQ(16, MY_VALUE<uint16_t>::val);
}
```

Linker error:

```
undefined reference to `MY_VALUE<unsigned char>::val
undefined reference to `MY_VALUE<unsigned short>::val
```

anyone an idea :)
Thanks

Comment: Please let us know in which files the templates live. All in headers?

Comment: Oh sorry. I don not see your comment. I am new on stackoverflow. I think it does not matter. I try it in Header file (original Code). The example above I wirte in the gtest cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the fact that assertion engine of GTEST requires reference. To have reference - variable needs to be defined:

```
template<>
struct MY_VALUE<uint8_t>{
        static const uint8_t val = 8;
};

// this line is missing 
// Note: do not put it in header - if you have multiple files project
const uint8_t MY_VALUE<uint8_t>::val;
```

Do the same for uint16_t.

IF you have compiler supporting C++17 - you might try to just add [inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) or constexpr to val:

```
template<>
struct MY_VALUE<uint8_t>{
        static constexpr uint8_t val = 8;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your answer helps.
Adding:

```
const uint8_t MY_VALUE<uint8_t>::val;
```

works.
I have no c++17 support.
I cant try this.

Comment: That should be a comment under my post. And to mark the answer as "working" - just accept it

Comment: Ups sorry. Next time